# Keep up to date a cpp-plugin(windows) for QGIS with less effort

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, c++

We have two c++-plugins for QGIS and thought with the LTR release we are bit saver against the fast version-changes. Today I updated my QGis from **2.14.0** to **2.14.4** and had to recognise, that the plugins couldn't been loaded. Could be the reason therefore the new QGIS is built and deployed with a **newer GDAL/OGR**?

Or is there for every build of QGis requiered to have a seperate build for the plugin?

So I have to download and update the sources again and recreate the VS Project for every subversion of the LTR?

> EDIT:

Found out, need new **gdal_i.lib** and **spatialite_i.lib** to compile, so I changed it in the Linker-Properties of my VS-Project.
Then I need the libs **qgis_core** and **qgis_gui**. Downloaded them with the qgis-devel and linked it. But now I get the following Linker error:

> Fehler    1058    error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: virtual bool __thiscall QgsSymbolLayerV2::writeDxf(class QgsDxfExport &,double,class QString const &,class QgsSymbolV2RenderContext *,class QgsFeature const *,class QPointF)const " (?writeDxf@QgsSymbolLayerV2@@UBE_NAAVQgsDxfExport@@NABVQString@@PAVQgsSymbolV2RenderContext@@PBVQgsFeature@@VQPointF@@@Z)". QGISFunc.obj    tb4qgisplugin

But in code I can't find any hint, never use sth like DXF. Any idea?

Comment: I suspect you will have to recompile against that version of QGIS?  Is there a reason they are C++ and not just Python which are a bit more portable?

Comment: The decision to develop a plugin was made in 2011(Wroclaw). Now it is just so. Probably our company has not enough ressources in time to port it to python.... Nevertheless don't understand, why bring out a 'stable' version with 0..1..2..3..4 subversions.

Comment: Well that is the point of the stable version, point releases.  I'm not sure you need to recompile that was a stab in the dark.

Comment: QGIS has moved from GDAL 1.11 to 2.1. This might break some plugins.

Comment: @AndreJ Yes, 2.14.0 is built with GDAL 2.0.2 and now it has 2.1. But how can I check this out? Is there somewhere a variable to use the old gdal, just to find the reason?

Comment: You can check it out with `Help -> About`. Using old GDAL is not possible, because QGIS is compiled against that GDAL version, and will not like older ones. Same as your plugin.

Comment: @AndreJ Thank you. This I checked out before asked this question, but I wasn't sure if this is really the only reason the plugin has broken. Searching for a way to compile with only linking the new gdal but think this is not possible.

Comment: @NathanW All my attempts to recompile with less investment failed. It's due to the new version of gdal. However... But it is really necessary to change the gdal during a ltr point release? Maybe there are good reasons, for me its a bit frustrating...

Comment: If you run QGIS on Ubuntu, you have little choice to stay with an old GDAL version. The precompiled binaries always use the latest available dependencies, everything else must be self-compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following I found out:

For deploying a cpp-plugin for QGIS it is requiered building the dll separately for every version - even point releases of a LTR. From this perspective it makes no difference if it is the actual or the ltr release. We have to take care that customers are using same version/point realease.

For setting up development environement I don't need to download every time complete source to setting up my VisualStudio-Project and compile QGIS. This I do only for a new LTR. For a new point release I defined this workflow for me (maybe someone helpes this)

1. with OSgeo4W-installer download the qgis-common and qgis-devel for ltr
2. in properties of the VisualStudio-project of the plugin:

   in section *C/C++* add *include path* `"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-ltr\include"`

   in section *linker->input* customize pathes to *additional dependances* i.e.`C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-ltr\lib\qgis_core.lib and C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-ltr\lib\qgis_gui.lib`
3. compiling the plugin now mustn't not fail and loading from QGIS without errors...hope this for the next